# Homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Suppose there is a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to R$  where $R$ is a non-zero ring.
By the definition of homomorphism $f(n)=f(1+1+1+1.....+1)=f(1)+f(1)+f(1)+....+f(1)$ 
Now suppose $f(1)=x$ then $f(n)=nx$ by definition. By varying x we can say that homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $0,\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{2Z},\mathbb{3Z}$...etc.

Am I right? Please provide some deep intuitions if any.

Comment: Image isn't really related to $\mathbb{Z}$ since ring $R$ might not even contain any integers.

Comment: Well in that case if R is a ring with unity then Z is embedded inside it. Question is what will be the homomorphic image is R has no unity?

Comment: Then is your question about what can be said about $f(\mathbb{Z})$ ? It is an additive subgroup of the additive part of $R$ generated by $f(1)$ and this doesn't require $R$ to have a unity. It may also be a subring but I didn't check that.

Comment: Yes sir I want to know the image of Z. Give me an example where the image is other than 0,Z,2Z,3Z etc.

Comment: I think your example is not a ring homomorphism. As a ring homomorphism preserves multiplication, we need $f(1)=f(1\cdot 1)=f(1)f(1)=x^2$ but by your definition $f(1)=x$, this is only possible if $x=1$ or $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ and define $f\colon \mathbf{Z}\to \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ to be the homomorphism $f(k) = k\pmod n$. The image is a ring with finitely many elements and  meets your requirement.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that if R has unity and the map is one one then Z is embedded inside R and if the map is not one one then the images are Zn(upto isomorphism ), Now if R has no unity then the map is trivial, I have to show this now...any hints?

Comment: If you are disregarding unity, just treat  **Z** as a group, focus on group homomorphisms defined there, and the images of such homomorphisms.

Comment: Okay I got my answer.. Ideals of Z are Z,(0),nZ then applying first isomorphism theorem image will be isomorphic to Z,0,Zn(upto isomorphism)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** : if $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \to R $ is a homorphism then $ \mathbb{Z}/ker(\phi) \cong \phi(\mathbb{Z}) $

now, ker($\phi$) is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ and any ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form **n$\mathbb{Z}$**